# express router.param using array of names

Tags: javascript, express

I'm trying to initialize multiple express router params using the router.param method. Here's a router code snippet:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.param(['foo','bar'], function(req,res,next,foo,bar){
  req.myvars = {
    foo: foo,
    bar: bar
  };
  console.log('initialized params: foo==%s, bar==%s', foo, bar);
  return next();
});

router.get('/myvars/:foo/:bar',function(req,res,next){
  var foo = req.myvars.foo;
  var bar = req.myvars.bar;
  console.log('router.get: foo==%s, bar==%s', foo, bar);
  res.json(req.myvars);
});

module.exports = router;
```

I'm getting an error when browsing to http://localhost:3000/myvars/a/b: **Cannot read property 'foo' of undefined**.  Also, my console window does *not* show the 'initialized params' like I expected. Is router.param not getting invoked? How do I use the router.param method properly?  I see many examples online ([eg. API  example](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router.param) of using router.param with only a *single* name: could someone give a code example of using router.param with an **array of names**?

If necessary, here's my package.json dependencies.

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.8.6",
    "body-parser": "~1.6.6",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.2",
    "morgan": "~1.2.3",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.0.1",
    "debug": "~1.0.4",
    "jade": "~1.5.0"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the Express router code, it doesn't actually accept an array of names (even though the documentation suggests it does).

You can work around it with something like this:

```
var handler = function(req, res, next, value, key) {
  req.myvars = req.myvars || {};
  req.myvars[key] = value;
  next();
};

router.param('foo', handler);
router.param('bar', handler);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it does support arrays, but you can't resolve both params at the same time. If you look at the docs again.

```
router.param(['id', 'page'], function (req, res, next, value) {
  console.log('CALLED ONLY ONCE with', value);
  next();
})
```

You have to access their values in a for each style. Also I don't know why you would return a `next()`. I don't think it will  cause any problems, but just call `next()` and let function terminate on its own.

Comment: The docs say it excepts arrays. but from looking at the source code, you can tell it would not work!

Comment: @Blind-Owl, I posted a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38337965/express-js-router-process-api-requests-with-multiple-parameters) because I too am having this issue. I tried following Express documentation and wrote an anonymous function that supports being run twice, for the two parameters in the URL. Any suggestion?